# What is the best way to export mysql ddl and table data to aws redshift?

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I have a bunch of tables in MySQL database and some of these tables have close to 3 million ~ 5 million rows each. I need to export the DDLs to create these tables in AWS Redshift and also export the data. I have played with a few processes like using mysqldump to create csv files. But this is creating very huge files and the process is taking forever to finish. I'm hoping there could be a better way to get around with this.

Comment: take a look at AWS DMS

Comment: Hey @JonScott Thanks for your reply. AWS DMS seems more like a enterprise level solution.

Comment: no - its not. you can get going quickly - read up

Comment: Take a look at the [AWS Schema Conversion Tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html).